# Paypal adaptive chain payment

Tags: php, paypal, payment, chain

I wish to implement paypal adaptive chain payment in my website .

Here the buyer uses credit card details for the transaction.
Then the cash is transferred to primary receiver.

then the primary receiver will transfer it to secondary receivers.

The paypal fee must only taken for the primary receiver transaction.

Is this possible with php.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Basically, you will have to create a new app at apps.paypal.com.
Submit the app for review and get it approved. While applying for the app, you could specify, who is going to pay the PayPal fee. One the APP is approved, you can use the APP-ID provided by them and use the below SDK as sample.

Sample [SDK](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php)